# Saving and restoring pandas display options

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to save the state of the display options for pandas, change them, and restore them later. Is there any way to do this without recording (and later restoring) each of the options one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options), see bottom of that section, this feature is new in 0.13.1

You can pass 1 or more options here

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns',1): 
     # do something cool
```